# material-icons with letter-spacing not seen well in ios browsers

Tags: css, ios, angular, icons

I am using star icons from angular material to show levels, my target was that the stars will be next to each other. For that I used `letter-spacing: -0.25rem;` my problems that it is not render at all in ios platforms (there is spaces between the icons). I tried to add `text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;` and `font-weight: normal;` but it still doesn't reflected on ios browsers, can someone know what is the soution for that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to say that I received a solution to this problem.
Instead of using the mat-icon tag, I changes it to i tag and add class="material-icons" and to the material-icons CSS class

```
.neg-margin > * {
  margin-right: -0.5em;
}
```

Link to solution:
https://codepen.io/GD_Design/pen/QWbYqxp?fbclid=IwAR1-emQXq1Yj3IjAonZUSCrCWYbVWmo283DGcvXNeNC0VqtvJ12vajCG7cg